# pip use on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, python, 16.04, pip

I installed python packages on Ubuntu Trusty using `pip` and was able to call the installed packages as expected, but on Ubuntu Xenial (installed in a virtual machine) I did the same thing using `pip` but could not use or see these packages until I installed these same packages via `apt-get` util.

Now my question are:

1. Does my running Xenial on a virtual machine change how `pip` works?
2. Or is there a change in Xenial on how `pip` works that I am should be aware of?
3. I was able to install packages on Trusty based on python2 or python3 and was to install using `pip` or `pip3`, so how would this work when I use `apt-get` to install or can I include version number when installing via `apt-get`.

Comment: Did you install pip?

Comment: @Raju, yes i did, both **pip** and **pip3**.

Comment: What is the output of `which pip` and `which pip3`? Also, try installing packages through `sudo pip`/`sudo pip3` instead of just `pip`/`pip3`

Comment: @Raju, I got this response when i used __"sudo pip3 install"__:   ` The directory '/home/george/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.` **BUT NOTE IT STILL INSTALLED**

Comment: @Raju, the `which pip` and `which pip3` give location of pips now but before installing using `apt-get` it returned nothing.